# How to get just one value from querystrig

Tags: asp.net, return-value, code-behind, key-value, qstring

I'm write this function:

```
public static String QueryString(string queryStringKey)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryStringKey] != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryStringKey].ToString() != string.Empty)
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.GetValues(1).ToString();
    }
    return "NAQ";
}
```

And i want to get just one value from querystring parameter.
for example i send "page" to my function and url is: "sth.com/?page=1&page=2"
and function return to me: "1,2" ; but i want first value: "1", How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx) returns a `string[]` if the key exists. An array is zero based, so you get the first element by using `array[0]`, you are using `GetValues(1)` in your code, i assume that you wanted the first.

You could also use the `Enumerable.First` extension method:

```
Request.QueryString.GetValues("page").First();
```

Since `GetValues` returns not an empty array but `null` if the key was not present you need to check that explicitely (`FirstOrDefault` doesn't work):

```
public static String QueryString(string queryStringKey)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Request != null)
    {
        string[] values = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.GetValues("queryStringKey");
        if (values != null) return values.First();
    }
    return "NAQ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be -

```
public static String QueryString(string queryStringKey)
{

    if (HttpContext.Current!=null && HttpContext.Current.Request!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryStringKey])
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.GetValues(queryStringKey).First();
    }
    return "NAQ";
}
```

Comment: Why is it better? You need to check the return value of `GetValues` anyway since it doesn't return an empty array but `null`. So this approach won't work even if it uses `FirstOrDefault`. Edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18357336/284240) accordingly.

Comment: Firstly - A better approach I meant in answer to the original question.
Second - Agree with you on `null` thing but wouldn't it be already considered if we have a null check in place in the if condition above?

Comment: Correct, the `if` should handle the case even if it would be better to check for `null` explicitely since the value could also be an empty string(then `NAQ"` would be returned even if the key exists). So `FirstOrDefault` is just confusing since it can never be an empty array.